# Scrollview in Interface Builder with Autolayout with content size dynamically set to screen size?

Tags: xcode, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview, interface-builder, autolayout

I want to set the content view of a scrollview to whatever the current screen size is, but AutoLayout is doing some funky stuff. This is trivial in code... just create a scrollview with a frame that is the superview's bounds. Then create a content view with the scrollview bounds and populate it and set the `alwaysBounces...` properties to YES. In interface builder though, this is some kind of sinful thing it seems.

I know Autolayout handles scrollviews totally differently because it wants to infer the content size based on constraints. My approach that failed is setting the scrollview to have 0 distance to its superview (all sides attached). Then, the same with the content view (the single scrollView subview)- attached to all superview edges. Then the precompiler thing complains about not knowing the content size, so I set a width and height constraint at placeholder to be removed at build time. But the result is a (CGRect){0,0,0,0} contentView. The 0 space to trailing edge and bottom of superview are totally ignored.

So how can I make a scrollview with a dynamic content size based on the screen size?

Bonus points if you can explain how you would do the same, but for a content size of 2x screen width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try setting a constraint for the content view's width to equal the scroll view's width (for your bonus question: with a multiplier of 2). Same for height.

Not sure what the point of having a scroll view whose content is always the size of the scroll view is. By definition it wouldn't scroll, right?

Comment: Thanks for the response. Without `alwaysScrollsVertical`/`horizontal` no, it wouldn't scroll. But these properties allow the content to scroll regardless of size. The effect is a view that the user can pull around while holding, but will rubberband back to its original coordinates when the user releases the long-press gesture (could also be achieved with UIKit dynamics, but this does the job. And also I want to configure a custom page view controller in storyboard- hence the 2x screen size question).